# For positive semi-definite symmetric complex matrices $A$, $B$, $B$ being full rank, for $\operatorname{tr}(A^H B)$ to be $0$, $A=0$ has to be true?

Tags: inner-products, matrix-rank, trace, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

I have two matrices $A$,$B$ given that both are positive semi-definite, symmetric, complex.
Another given is that $B$ has full rank.
Now I want to find a condition that implies (or is equivalent to) $\operatorname{tr}(A^H B)=0$.
My idea is that it should be $A=0$.
But I am not sure how to get there.

Comment: Can you maybe specify what H is?

Comment: Of Course, the H is the conjugate transpose. 
Alternatively it should suffice to show this for $trace(A^T B)$

Comment: Tip: Write "the trace of a matrix M" as $\operatorname{tr}(\mathbf{M})$ (code is ```\operatorname{tr}```)

Answer (score 0):

Writing $B$ in the basis in which it is diagonal we have
$$
B = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i v_iv_i^*,
$$
where $\lambda_i > 0$ for all $i = 1, \dots, n$ and $\{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ form an orthonormal basis. Note that $B$ must be positive definite as it has full rank. Writing $A$ with respect to this basis,
$$
A = \sum_{ij} a_{ij} v_i v_j^*. 
$$
Computing the trace we find (assuming as $A$ is PSD it is also Hermitian)
$$
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Tr}[ A^* B] &= \operatorname{Tr}[\sum_{ij} a_{ij} v_i v_j^* \sum_k \lambda_k v_k v_k^*] \\
&=  \operatorname{Tr}[\sum_{ij} \lambda_j a_{ij} v_i v_j^*] \\
&=  \sum_{j} \lambda_j a_{jj}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Now as $\lambda_j > 0$ the only way this sum can be zero (given $a_{jj} \geq 0$) is if $a_{jj} = 0$ for all $j$. However this means that $\operatorname{Tr}[A]=0$, together with the fact that $A$ is PSD this implies $A=0$.

Thus in the context of this question $\operatorname{Tr}[A^* B] = 0 \implies A = 0$. The converse is immediate and so if $A$ and $B$ are PSD and $B$ has full rank then $\operatorname{Tr}[A^* B] = 0 \iff A=0$.